# Is it ok to have terraform state in Azure blob as public?

Tags: azure, security, terraform

I want to have Terraform's backend in Azure Storage Account. I'm following [this article by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/terraform/store-state-in-azure-storage?tabs=terraform).

And, I quote from the article

> Public access is allowed to Azure storage account for storing
> Terraform state.

But wouldn't that make the state downloadable publicly, hence it will expose our infrastructure?

What's the best practice here? Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct having your storage account publicly available is a bad idea. Best practice is to have your backend state file in a blob container that is locked down (usually with a firewall and the public access level of the container set to private). And then you can use any of the ways seen [here](https://www.terraform.io/language/settings/backends/azurerm) to authenticate to Azure. I personally use a service principal as it is easy to set up and avoids using user credentials and access keys.